# Perl - how to write changes to a file instead of seeing the console output only

Tags: perl

I found this command on SO which is exactly what I wanted to know but I only see the console output. I need the command to re-write the file it's working on (file.txt). This command takes every number (well, positive integer) in a file that is greater than 400 and add 13 to it.

```
perl -pe 's/\d+/$& > 400 ? $&+13 : $&/ge' file.txt
```

Comment: `$&` has nasty down sides. While it doesn't matter in that snippet, it's a bad habit and completely unnecessary. `perl -i -pe 's/(\d+)/$1 > 400 ? $1+13 : $1/ge' file.txt`

Comment: `$&` is necessary for code golf :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the option -i for in-place editing:

```
perl -i -pe 's/\d+/$& > 400 ? $&+13 : $&/ge' file.txt
```

Comment: Tried it. I just got error about can't do inline edit without backup.

Comment: Ok, the -i needs .bak extension for windows systems (-i.bak). That's it, works!

Comment: Except I forgot that I need it to search for the 3 characters "var" before the number it starts at, so "var400" is what I need.

Comment: `perl -i.bak -pe 's/var(\d+)/"var".($1 > 400 ? $1+13 : $1)/ge' file.txt`.  $& is matches string, $1 is first capture group (first set of parens), so it should be equivalent.